# How to use DataProtectionKeys with multiple applications?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, encryption, containers, data-protection

I'm running with the code below and I can see that one key is created in the table [DataProtectionKeys]

```
    services.AddDataProtection()
        .SetApplicationName(dataProtectionSettings.ApplicationName)
        .ProtectKeysWithCertificate(serviceCertificate)
        .UnprotectKeysWithAnyCertificate(serviceCertificate)
        .PersistKeysToDbContext<DataProtectionContext>();
```

I'm using this database context (am I missing something?):

```
class DataProtectionContext : DbContext, IDataProtectionKeyContext
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A recommended constructor overload when using EF Core with dependency injection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="options"></param>
    public DataProtectionContext(DbContextOptions<DataProtectionContext> options)
        : base(options) { }

    /// <summary>
    /// This maps to the table that stores keys.
    /// </summary>
    public DbSet<DataProtectionKey> DataProtectionKeys { get; set; }
}
```

But, if I change to ApplicationName string value to something else, I don't see that a new key is created

Any idea why or how to fix it so this database table can support multiple application

Comment: What if you could write only for single application? Is that work for that scenario? Or doesn't work while writing for `multiple applications?`

Comment: Hi, it seems to be working when I use a different application name - but only one key is created, I start wondering if it is maybe a bug (I' using an older .NET 5 for this one).

Comment: @Yovav did you figure out a solution to this?

Comment: No, only one key is created, although multiple applications can use the same key, maybe it's an Entity Framework bug